# MySql GROUP BY, ORDER BY LIMIT query taking more than 5000 seconds

Tags: mysql-5.6, performance, slow-log, query-performance

I have a simple table. In which one composite index is created. We have a job which hits select statement on slave server and which takes around 5000 seconds to execute query.
Please check table and query below with explain output :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `abc_mins` (
  `abc_key` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `a_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `location` (`location`,`a_time`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select location, a_time, sum(val) val from abc_mins where abc_key like 'xyz:requests:3189:%' and location='Pune' group by 1,2 order by 1,2 desc limit 4;
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | abc_mins            | ref  | location      |location| 753   | const | 2422060 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```

```
mysql> EXPLAIN DELETE FROM abc_mins WHERE a_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 65 MINUTE); 
`
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table               | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | abc_mins            | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 16454335 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried by adding one more index on a_time column but no luck.
DELETE query getting execute on master and replicate on slave. And SELECT query get execute on slave only.
mysql version 5.6
binlog format mix on master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try an index for:

```
location, abc_key, a_time
```

If you want to stretch that a bit and create a covering index

```
location, abc_key, a_time, val
```

Hovever, a table without a primary key is a bit suspicious. In fact, nothing is mandatory. You may want to investiga why this is so, and if possible fix

Comment: Selects are running fantastic but slave is continuously behind master. Its in state of 

| system user   |                     | NULL      | Connect | 65173 | Waiting for master to send event | NULL 

| system user   |                     | NULL      | Connect |  4165 | Reading event from the relay log | NULL

I guess because of index inserts and delete became slow.

Comment: For delete you will benefits from an index on a_time

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
select  location, a_time, sum(val) val
    from  abc_mins
    where  abc_key like 'xyz:requests:3189:%'
      and  location='Pune'
    group by  1,2
    order by  1,2 desc
    limit  4;
```

`INDEX(location, abc_key)` *in this order* will allow it to filter down to very few rows to group and sort.

Having `INDEX(location, a_time)` may help with the `GROUP BY`, but cannot help with the `ORDER BY` (since you not using 8.0).  Hence there will be a big temp file before delivering only 4 results.

But, there is a problem with `VARCHAR(500) CHARSET utf8`.  But, but, I provide 5 workarounds [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) -- you decide which, if any, can be applied for your case.  Note that this implies that Lennart's suggestions won't work without some workaround.

As for slave lag -- Is this `SELECT` bogging down the Slave?  If after fixing the indexing here, you still have a lagging slave, then start a new Question with your next theory of lag.

Meanwhile, turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time=1` and `log_slow_slave_statements=ON`.

The lack of a `PRIMARY KEY` is naughty, but probably does not impact this `SELECT`.

If the `DELETEs` causing the trouble, I have several suggestions [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)